# BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery problems with datasets located in EU

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have problems with querying BigQuery tables/datasets located in EU. The problem was reported here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/86

I made workaround in createDataset method of BigQueryTableRowIterator with setting location to EU. This fix works if i run Pipeline with DirectPipelineRunner, but fails with DataflowPipelineRunner. The main reason are datasets named like _dataflow_temp_dataset*. This datasets are located in US and not in EU... I can't find the lines of code where these datasets are created. In BigQueryTableRowIterator temporary datsets are created with name schema:

```
temporaryDatasetId = "_dataflow_temporary_dataset_" + rnd.nextInt(1000000);
```

Does anybody have any idea for an workaround of this bug until there's a final fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix in the works for this, which will use location-aware temporary dataset in the dataflow pipeline.

In the mean-time, you can contact cloud support and they can set a default location for your bigquery tables. If you set the default location to EU, this means that the temporary dataset used by Dataflow will also be in the EU.